# Put strings in List<string> and output

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms, list

I have a test project that puts 4 strings to a list but can't seem to do it right. I am trying to view my list in 2 textboxes using the for and foreach loops.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string[]> testList2 = new List<string[]>();

    string[] text = { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text };
    testList2.Add(text);

    textBox5.Text = testList2.Count.ToString();

    foreach (string[] list1 in testList2)
    {
        foreach (string list2 in list1)
        {
            textBox6.Text = list2.ToString();
        }
    }
    string temp = testList2.ToString();
    for (int i = 0; i < testList2.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            textBox7.Text = testList2[j].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the loops where not showing all the string inside the list. The answer below worked for the foreach but the for looped didn't show any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without you telling us what your problem is i can only guess that not all values are in textbox that you want. You should use AppendText instead of Text

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string[]> testList2 = new List<string[]>();

        String[] text = { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text };
        testList2.Add(text);

        textBox5.Text = testList2.Count.ToString();

        foreach (string[] list1 in testList2)
        {
            foreach (string list2 in list1)
            {
                textBox6.AppendText(list2);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < testList2.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                textBox7.AppendText(testList2[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I am correct what you try to make is a List of strings. If that is so, there is no reason for nesting. Is this what you want?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<String> testList2= new List<String>();

        testList2.Add(textBox1.Text);
        testList2.Add(textBox2.Text);
        testList2.Add(textBox3.Text);
        testList2.Add(textBox4.Text);

        textBox5.Text = testList2.Count.ToString();

        foreach (String val in testList2)
        {      
            textBox6.AppendText(val);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < testList2.Count; i++)
        {
            textBox7.AppendText(testList2[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked for the for loop. But for the foreach loop it only  shows the string from textbox1. Tried to put an increment on list2[i] but still didn't work

Comment: Sorry it was The for loop that is having a problem not the foreach loop.

Comment: Which loop is the "top" one?

Comment: The for loop doesn't output anything sir.

Comment: First of all I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Second of all, in your for loop you only access first level, you have an array inside a List

Comment: sorry for not stating my problem well sir. For the for loop im also trying to output all the data inside my list. Im trying to acheive the following output :
txtbox1 = 1
txtbox2 = 2
txtbox3 = 3
txtbox4 = 4

txtbox6 and 7 should output= 1234

Comment: Check my second solution. I'm not sure why you want two loops, it could all be done in one. (i made some stupid mistakes, too used to Java)

Comment: I just wanted to show the output using different loops sir. I got an error with .get(i) it says : 

Error 1'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'get' and no extension method 'get' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: got it sir just changed it to testList2[i] and it worked thank you so much for you time.